# Hive - Is it a good fit for building a datawarehouse?

Tags: hadoop, hive, data-warehouse

So like most Enterprise companies, we have built a data warehouse in Hadoop, with user queries supported in Hive, and now after a few months and user acceptance testing everyone is a little surprised about how it is not like a standard (Oracle/Netezza) database when used by end-users for ad-hoc data analysis. 
While I understand that this is probably a very stupid way of doing projects (we should have researched the use cases and best fit technologies before building the product), and I know the basic technical aspects of how Hadoop differs from single node machines... I would still want to understand if using Hadoop/Hive makes sense for data warehouses in any scenario? 
For instance,

- Are there always trade-offs in query performance or can they be optimized with configuration changes, horizontal scaling of hardware?
- Can it ever be as fast as something like Netezza - which uses non-commodity hardware but functions on a similar architecture?
- Where is Hadoop great and absolutely defeats everything else in comparison?

Comment: For ad-hoc queries, Impala, Presto, Drill, or Tez are better choices that work in the Hadoop ecosystem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would argue the Hive **MetaStore** is useful more than HiveServer2 itself as the query interface.

The MetaStore is what Presto and Spark use to get data much quicker than MapReduce, but maybe not as fast as a well-optimized Tez query, and improvements are being made in Hive v2.x+ with LLAP, for example.

In the end, Hive is really only useful if the ingestion pipelines are actually storing the data in columnar formats of ORC or Parquet to begin with. From there, and reasonable query engine can scan through that data fairly quickly, and Hive just happens to be considered the defacto implementation of that access pattern, whereas Impala or Presto are often more used for adhoc access.

That being said, Hive (and other SQL on Hadoop) is not used for "building", it is used for "analyzing"

And I don't know what you mean by "standard" - Hive supports any ODBC/JDBC Connection, so it's not like you go to the CLI for all access, and HUE or Zeppelin make really nice notebooks for SQL analysis over Hive.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question,

> 1. Are there always trade-offs in query performance or can they be optimized with configuration changes, horizontal scaling of hardware?

If you are using only hive tool from Hadoop for Adhoc querying then that is not right choice for adhoc querying and data analysis. We have explore better option according to you use case and make tech selection from Hive LLAP, HBase, Spark, SparkSQL, Spark Streaming, Apache storm, Imapala, Apache Drill and Prestodb etc.

> 2. Can it ever be as fast as something like Netezza - which uses non-commodity hardware but functions on a similar architecture?

It is better tool now days most of organization using but you have to be specific about tech tools selection from Hadoop tech stack according to you use case and after studying it do right selection for technology.

> 3. Where is Hadoop great and absolutely defeats everything else in comparison?

Hadoop is best for implementing data lake platform in large organization where data scattered across multiple systems, and using Hadoop data lake you can have data at center place. Which can leveraged as data analytics platform for organization data which accumulated over the time period. Also can be used for data stream data processing to get results in real time.

Hope this will help.

Answer (score -1):

Well, there are many benefits of using storing big data in HDFS or say Hadoop ecosystem. To name the most important ones, someone is there who can store and process huge data and the configuration is pretty straight forward.

Comment: This doesn't really address the question about Hive

Comment: Hive provides tools to enable easy data ETL, a mechanism to put structures on the data, and the capability for querying and analysis of large datasets stored in Hadoop files.  
Hive Partitions is a way to organizes tables into partitions by dividing tables into different parts based on partition keys. For example- If you need any month wise report for analytics, it's better to ingest data in month wise partition rather than ingesting select * from table.